# How do I manipulate an Int in main by passing its address down through two functions in C?

Tags: c, function, pointers, memory-address

I have an int in main called 'end'.

Main calls in a function, which itself call in a function.

So far I am able to have the first function manipulate 'end' by sending it an address and having it expect a pointer. I cannot however send that down to the next function, and have it manipulate the 'int' called in in main.

So far I have the following which works for one function;

Abbreviated code which works for one function:

```
void function(int* end);

int main(void)
{
   end = 0;

   function(&end);
}

void function(int* end)
{
   *end = 1;

   // At this stage I want to call in another function, and have it be able to manipulate 'end'
}
```

Comment: You can do this for very simple programs, but there is a reason that C and C++ default to pass-by-value, unlike FORTRAN. Otherwise, you can end up in situations where 8 different functions are touching the variable.

Answer (score 6):

Just keep passing the pointer.

```
void function2( int *end ) {
    *end += 41;
}

void function( int *end ) {
    *end = 1;
    function2( end );
}
```

Comment: Why not just pass the int down as a return value? Seems a bit simpler.

Comment: Unfortunately the return is being used at the moment

Comment: Thanks Paddy, I will try that

Comment: @EdHeal Sure, but it's not always appropriate, and the OP specifically asked about passing an existing pointer into another function.

Comment: @paddy - I left it as a comment. Some people seem to want to make things more complicated that they need to be.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that in your function you already have an integer pointer- make sure you are continuing to pass the pointer `end` rather than the address to the pointer `&end`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void function( int *end );
void another_function( int *end );

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
   int end = 0;
   function( &end );
   printf( "end: %d\n", end );
}

void function( int *end ) {
   *end = 1;
   another_function( end );
}

void another_function( int *end ) {
   (*end)++;
}
```

Outputs:
`end: 2`